# How edit job in sidekiq queue?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sidekiq

I have a queue that happened to contain wrong parameters for the perform_async worker. I don't want to loose the jobs, but edit arguments so they will succeed next time or on forced retry.

Is this possible?

Answer (score -3):

Sidekiq stores his jobs in Redis so maybe try using some GUI for redis (like http://redisdesktop.com/) find job you need to update, edit, save. It can be done in some loop to update multiple of them.